# javascript banner - close button doesn't work corectly

Tags: javascript

I made a javascript banner which expands on rollover and close on click on a button. I cannot close it when the the banner is still expanding. When i click on the close button the banner expands and only after it starts to close. I thisnk it's about clear interval but but i dont't know how to resolve the problem. Can anyone help me?

```js
    var dagContainer = document.querySelector('.dag_sideslider');
    var side_btn = document.querySelector('.side_btn');
    var close_btn = document.querySelector('.dag_close');
    side_btn.addEventListener("mouseover", open);
    close_btn.addEventListener("click", closeBanner);

function open() {

    side_btn.style.display = "none";
    close_btn.style.display = "block";
    var pos = 300;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 5);

    function frame() {
        if (pos == 900) {
            clearInterval(id);
        } else {
            pos++;
            dagContainer.style.width = pos + 'px';
        }
    }
}

function closeBanner() {

    close_btn.style.display = "block";
    var idd = setInterval(framee, 5);

    function framee() {

        var poss = dagContainer.offsetWidth;
        console.log(poss);
        if (poss == 300) {
            clearInterval(idd);
            console.log("ss");
            close_btn.style.display = "none";
            side_btn.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            poss--;
            console.log(poss)
            dagContainer.style.width = poss + 'px';
            console.log(poss);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
  .slideSider_container{
   margin:0 auto 0;
   position: relative;
   width: 300px;
   height: 600px;
  }
  .dag_sideslider{
   background-color:#ea7900;
   width: 300px;
   height: 600px;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top:0;  
  }
  .side_btn{
   width: 300px;
   height: 600px;
  }
  .dag_close{
   position: absolute;
   top:0px;
   right: 0px;
   z-index:9999;
   display: none
  }
```

```html
<div class="slideSider_container">
 <div class="dag_sideslider" >
  <div class="dag_close"><img src="close.png"></div>
  <div class="side_btn"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve] using the `<>` button in the question editor.

Comment: i did it. Can you take a look, pleae? thanks!

Comment: You just need to clear the previous interval

Comment: i suppose i need to clear it but how to do that?

Comment: When you store the interval (`id = setInterval(...)`), the variable is local to the function. Move its declaration outside so you can access it from anywhere in your code, then call `clearInterval` on it.

Comment: it works! Thank you very much!!!